# Draw a filled circle at every point of a TikZ plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

Consider the following simple example:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (b) at (1,1);
  \coordinate (c) at (2,0);

  \draw (a) -- (b) -- (c);

  \fill (a) circle (2pt);
  \fill (b) circle (2pt);
  \fill (c) circle (2pt);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I am interested in improving this code. In particular I would like to avoid the manual drawing of the circles. Have in mind a case where many vertices are involved with many different names.

I know I could replace the fill's with some loop like

```
  \foreach \i in {a,b,c}
  \fill (\i) circle (2pt);
```

But I'm interested in more global magic, that is a way to fill a circle (or any other shape) of some fixed radius radius (or dimension) whenever TikZ meets a coordinate.

A bonus would be a solution which can be switched off for certain vertices. I believe the solution is to use `style`'s but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Why don’t you use `plot` with a `plotmark`? You could also use the `show path construction` decoration which allows access to the coordinates. Otherwise you will need to hack TikZ, I guess. `:)`

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: I guess the simplest answer is because I don't know these options... `plot` together with `plotmark` seems to be a solution. How can I determine the shape /size of the mark? `show path construction` seems to be an overkill, or simply too complicated...

Answer (score 8):

With a `plot` you can use `mark`s. This allows to use the marks `*`, `x`, `+` and `ball`. More plot marks can be loaded with the `plotmarks` library.

Available options are

- **`mark`**,
- `mark repeat`,
- `mark phase`,
- `mark indices`,
- **`mark size`**,
- the style `every mark`,
- `mark options` (which simply sets `every mark`) and
- `no marks` and `no markers` (which are the same as `mark=none`).

and with the `plotmarks` library

- `mark color` (for the *other* color of the starred half versions),
- `text mark` (text used for the `text` mark),
- `text mark as node` and
- `text mark style`

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[anchor=mid west,
  mark size=+2pt, mark color=blue, text mark=Ti\emph{k}Z, ball color=green]
  \foreach \plm[count=\cnt] in {*, x, +, ball, % always loaded, ball only with TikZ
      -, |, o, asterisk, star, 10-pointed star,
      oplus, oplus*, otimes, otimes*, triangle, triangle*, diamond, diamond*,
      halfdiamond*, halfsquare*, halfsquare right*, halfsquare left*,
      pentagon, pentagon*, Mercedes star, Mercedes star flipped, halfcircle, halfcircle*,
      heart, text}
    \draw[mark options={fill=red}, shift=(down:\cnt/2.5)]
      plot[mark=\plm] coordinates {(0,0) (1,.5) (2,0)} node {\quad\ttfamily\plm};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]